# Signed Word to Integer Conversion in Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, integer-arithmetic

I'd like some help in understanding and fixing an SBCL compiler note that says:

```
; in: DEFUN PRINT-SEARCH-PROGRESS-GRAPH
;     (- (1+ WOULDWORK-PKG::*N*)
;        (LENGTH WOULDWORK-PKG::*L*))
;
; note: doing signed word to integer coercion (cost 20), for:
;       the first result of inline (signed-byte 64) arithmetic
```

Some possibly relevant background info:

```
(optimize (debug 3))

(defparameter *N* 0)
(declaim (fixnum *N*))
    
(defparameter *L* nil)
(declaim (list *L*))
    
(type-of *N*) => BIT
```

Comment: Change `(fixnum *N*)` to `(integer *N*)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared `*N*` to be a `FIXNUM`, which is a fixed-size integer; it's equivalent to `(SIGNED-BYTE 64)` in 64-bit SBCL. But if its value happens to be `MOST-POSITIVE-FIXNUM`, `(1+ *n*)` could produce a value that's doesn't fit in 64 bits, so it will have to convert to `INTEGER`. The note is warning you that this conversion may take place.

If you know that it will never be so high that this overflow will be necessary, you can use `THE`:

```
(- (the fixnum (1+ *n*)) (length *l*))
```

Comment: Regarding the first fix, the variable `*N*` needs to be a `fixnum` because I'm declaring it with `sb-ext:defglobal` to enable parallel updating. As for the second fix using "the fixnum", I get the same compiler note as before.

Comment: It's probably because `(length *l*)` has no reason to be a fixnum (hence, the subtraction probably has to be the "generic" one). Moreover, subtracting two fixnums might still result in a "bignum":
- you can wrap every expression in `(the fixnum ...)`
- or you declare (possibly locally) what you know, *e.g.* `(declare (type (integer 0 42) *N*))` if you know the precise bounds of `*N*`
- in general, write the rest of the program, and profile to see if this ONE operation is relevant to performance at all.

Comment: Yes, it looks like there's the potential for exceeding the most-negative-fixnum too. Moving "the fixnum" to the front of the expression works, evidently because sbcl can then figure out the internal expressions. Appreciate the insights.

Comment: @Numbra: in fact in 64-bit SBCL (and I am sure in 32-bit as well) `length` must return a fixnum, and SBCL knows this (the longest possible list has a length which is a fixnum, and `array-dimension-limit` is a fixnum.